# How to block user input based on a list of chars?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, keyboard

I have a list of chars:

```
var l = new List<char>();
l.AddRange(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
l.AddRange(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
```

I want to detect when the user press one of the blocked characters and set `SupressKeyPress` to `true`.

I have `e.KeyCode`, `e.KeyData` and `e.KeyValue`, but none of them corresponds to `?`, for example.

How can I validate it?

Comment: are you handling the `Control.KeyPress` event?  Without saying what event you're handling, or what the data type of `e` is, I'm afraid no one will be able to help you.

Comment: `KeyDown` actually. But I can use any key press event.

Comment: What is SupressKeyPress? It doesn't seem to be a property of any .NET Framework class...

Comment: @Thomas: A property on `KeyEventArgs` of `KeyDown` event.

Comment: oh, I see... I couldn't find it in the index because there was a typo, which I blindly copy pasted ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress the `KeyPress` by setting the `Handled` value to true:

```
var l = new List<char>();
l.AddRange(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
l.AddRange(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());

this.KeyPress += (s, e) =>
{
    e.Handled = l.Any(x => x == e.KeyChar);
};
```

Comment: I see, I can't use `KeyDown`. I didn't notice the eventargs where so different.

Comment: Also, technically it probably should be (sender, eventargs) as that is what is passed to the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Doesn't seem to work, at least not for me.

The property that did work with a KeyDown Event with:

```
e.SupressKeyPress;
```

Since KeyDown occurs before KeyPress or KeyUp Events, I "filtered" keys I wanted to handle in an additional KeyDown event.

[SupressKeyPress Property MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx)